# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii1.x

I have downloaded one project from liver server. I have made the config changes. But when I access this project I am getting following error

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
```

My index.php

```
<?php
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');

//  set environment
//error_reporting('~E_NOTICE');
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/protected/extensions/yii-environment/Environment.php');
$env = new Environment();

//$env = new Environment('PRODUCTION'); //override mode

// set debug and trace level
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', $env->yiiDebug);
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', $env->yiiTraceLevel);


// run Yii app
//$env->showDebug(); // show produced environment configuration

require_once($env->yiiPath);
//echo '<pre>';print_r($env);exit();
$env->runYiiStatics(); // like Yii::setPathOfAlias()

Yii::createWebApplication($env->configWeb)->run();
```

The project is IN YII 1.1x frmaework. Please suggest me how can I remove this error

Comment: What file are you trying to require? What is the code requiring it? Looks like you're trying ti require a blank file which explains the error.

Comment: You don't remeve error, you fix errors,  paste the code that gave u this error as well

Comment: I have edited my question.Please see my index.php file

Comment: One of the values you are passing through to `require_once` is blank. It is very likely to be `$env->yiiPath` or another blank being required. Check if that value is what you think it should be. You want to check first whether `$env->yiiPath` is valid before you attempt to use `require_once`.